# jQuery - how to remove this code redundancy

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am taking a course on Client side web development, and we are currently learning jQuery. I have an assignment that seems simple enough, yet I am stuck. The instructions are to refactor our code to make it adhere to the OOP DRY principle. In other words, remove the redundancy in the code for the face parts click functions.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="frame">
  <div id="pic_box">
    <div id="head" class="face"><img src="images/headsstrip.jpg"></div>
    <div id="eyes" class="face"><img src="images/eyesstrip.jpg"></div>
    <div id="nose" class="face"><img src="images/nosesstrip.jpg"></div>
    <div id="mouth" class="face"><img src="images/mouthsstrip.jpg"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var headclix = 0,
    eyeclix = 0,
    noseclix = 0,
    mouthclix = 0;

$("#head").click(function () {
    if (headclix < 9) {
        $("#head").animate({
            left: "-=367px"
        }, 500);
        headclix++;
    } else {
        $("#head").animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 500);
        headclix = 0;
    }
});

$("#eyes").click(function () {
    if (eyeclix < 9) {
        $("#eyes").animate({
            left: "-=367px"
        }, 500);
        eyeclix++;
    } else {
        $("#eyes").animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 500);
        eyeclix = 0;
    }
});

$("#nose").click(function () {
    if (noseclix < 9) {
        $("#nose").animate({
            left: "-=367px"
        }, 500);
        noseclix++;
    } else {
        $("#nose").animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 500);
        noseclix = 0;
    }
});

$("#mouth").click(function () {
    if (mouthclix < 9) {
        $("#mouth").animate({
            left: "-=367px"
        }, 500);
        mouthclix++;
    } else {
        $("#mouth").animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 500);
        mouthclix = 0;
    }
});

}); //end doc.onready function
```

Here is what I tried:

It seems silly looking at it, I am very new to this, so I am sure I was not even close.

```
$("#pic_box").children("#head #eyes #nose #mouth").click(function () {
    if (headclix, eyesclix, noseclix, mouthclix < 9) {
        $("#head #eyes #nose #mouth").animate({
            left: "-=367px"
        }, 500);
        headclix++, eyesclix++, noseclix++, mouthclix++;
    } else {
        $("#head #eyes #nose #mouth").animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 500);
        headclix, eyesclix, noseclix, mouthclix = 0;
    }
    });
```

Comment: And what was your attempt? Please include that as well.

Comment: Using the common class and data attributes in the html would let you do this easily with one event listener. `this` within the event handler will be the element event occurred on

Comment: Questions on how to refactor/optimize working code or better suited to be asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I will enter my attempt above.

Comment: You said you're stuck but did not explain what led you to that conclusion. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and remember that you're asking volunteers for help. If you've already tried _x, y,_ and _z_, then explain why those did not work and why you're stuck as a result. And if have code you want to add, then edit your original question to include it. Do not include it in a comment.

Comment: You missed the lesson about `$(this)`, please watch it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var clicks = {
    head: 0,
    eyes: 0,
    nose: 0,
    mouth: 0,
  }

  $("#head, #eyes, #nose, #mouth").click(function() {

    var clickedElementId = this.id;

    if (clicks[clickedElementId] < 9) {
      $(this).animate({
        left: "-=367px"
      }, 500);

      clicks[clickedElementId]++;
    } else {
      $(this).animate({
        left: "0px"
      }, 500);

      clicks[clickedElementId] = 0;
    }
  });

});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bzp0f1rn/2/)

Comment: Why use `$(\`#${clickedElementId}\`)`  instead of `$(this)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them into a single event handler, and then check the ID:

```
$("#head, #eyes, #nose, #mouth").click(function () {
    var clix;
    switch (this.id) {
        case "head": 
            clix = headclix;
            break;
        case "eyes":
            clix = eyesclix;
            break;
        case "nose":
            clix = noseclix;
            break;
        case "mouth":
            clix = mouthclix;
            break;
    }
    if (clix < 9) {
        $(this).animate({
            left: "-=367px"
        }, 500);
        headclix++;
    } else {
        $(this).animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 500);
        headclix = 0;
    }
    switch (this.id) {
        case "head": 
            headclix = 0;
            break;
        case "eyes":
            eyesclix = 0;
            break;
        case "nose":
            noseclix = 0;
            break;
        case "mouth":
            mouthclix = 0;
            break;
    }
});
```

It would be even simpler if you replaced the separate variables with an object whose keys are the IDs.

Comment: This answer offers a valid perspective +1

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two approaches to reach the objective of making the script DRY.

### 1. Rudimentary refactoring

Implement a factory function, `createEventHandler`, which should be called to create the respective handlers. This approach is probably in the scope of your requirement, but it's naive since it ignores the *context* of the script execution.

```
function createEventHandler( targetElementId, clickCountFrequencyMap ) {

    var targetElementSelector = "#" + targetElementId;

    function targetElementClickHandler( /* event */ ) {

        var targetElementClix = clickCountFrequencyMap[ targetElementId ];

        if ( targetElementClix < 9 ) {
            $( targetElementSelector ).animate( {
                left: "-=367px"
            }, 500 );
            targetElementClix++;
        } else {
            $( targetElementSelector ).animate( {
                left: "0px"
            }, 500 );
            targetElementClix = 0;
        }

        // Update the click frequency map.
        // --
        // Even though we're doing so at this point in the scope
        // of the objective you want to reach,
        // do note though that it's an absolute bad practice
        // to mutate a reference that's passed to a function.
        // Please do NOT take this comment lightly.

        clickCountFrequencyMap[ targetElementId ] = targetElementClix;
    }
}
```

So that your original script reduces to the following:

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    var clickCountFrequencyMap = {
        head: 0,
        eyes: 0,
        nose: 0,
        mouth: 0
    };

    $( "#head" ).click( createEventHandler( "head", clickCountFrequencyMap ) );

    $( "#eyes" ).click( createEventHandler( "eyes", clickCountFrequencyMap ) );

    $( "#nose" ).click( createEventHandler( "nose", clickCountFrequencyMap ) );

    $( "#mouth" ).click( createEventHandler( "mouth", clickCountFrequencyMap ) );
} );
```

This first approach probably fits into your current scope of learning. Eventually, as you progress you'll understand how to improve on it.

### 2. Use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

This approach gives due consideration to the script's execution environment: the script is being executed in a browser and it is manipulating the DOM.

Currently, it specifically takes care of clicks on 4 items (head, eye, nose and mouth). But you'll be right to expect that it would be requested of you to additionally handle clicks on the neck, and chest etc. Then the way to be future-proof and scalable in this case is to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

[@Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333744/adam)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53471325/1356062) demonstrates this already. For the sake of completion, I'll share a revised version below:

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    var clickCountFrequencyMap = {
        head: 0,
        eyes: 0,
        nose: 0,
        mouth: 0
    };

    $( document ).click( function () {

        var targetElement = $( this );
        var targetElementClix = clickCountFrequencyMap[ this.id ];

        if ( targetElementClix < 9 ) {
            targetElement.animate( {
                left: "-=367px"
            }, 500 );
            targetElementClix++;
        } else {
            targetElement.animate( {
                left: "0px"
            }, 500 );
            targetElementClix = 0;
        }

        // Update the click frequency map.
        // --
        // Even though we're doing so at this point in the scope
        // of the objective you want to reach,
        // do note though that it's an absolute bad practice
        // to mutate a reference that's passed to a function.
        // Please do NOT take this comment lightly.
        clickCountFrequencyMap[ targetElementId ] = targetElementClix;
    } );
} );
```